# Replace first `m` elements of an array

Tags: arrays, r

I have an array of length `n`. I'd like to replace its first `m<n` elements with 0. Obviously, a simple for loop can perform this task:

```
m<-100
n<-1000
x<-runif(n)
for(i in 1:m){
  x[i]<-0
}
```

Is there a more efficient solution? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a 2d or 3d array

Comment: try `x[1:m] <- 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'm' is the index of elements, use

```
replace(x, 1:m, 0)
```

Or

```
x * rep(c(0, 1), c(m, n - m))
```

Or

```
x * (seq_len(n) > m)
```

EDIT: Based on @RuiBarradas comments

Comment: Instead of `c(100, 900)` it would be more general to do `c(m, n - m)`.